# I'm not finding the path of storyboards

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm not finding the path of storyboards.

I'm trying to find a way to update my storyboard remotely.

I'm trying to do this because the xcode edit the arcquive.storyboard as an xml using the open.

But I can not find the path of a storyboard both base.lproj as the main path through the Bundle.

Whenever I check the file says it did not find any file.

Images:

[image: storyboards]

[image: code mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can find your storyboard / storyboards in the folder `Base.lproj`

*Details*:

In Xcode 5 and later, base internationalization is enabled by default.

Xcode creates a `Base.lproj` folder in your project folder and adds to it the resource files you select. Xcode creates a language folder for the development language but only adds resources that need translation to the folder. For example, if you select English as the development language, Xcode inserts the resource file in the Base.lproj project folder but not the en.lproj folder because the resource is already in English.

Comment: So alessandro I know but I wanted to do this upgrade remotely

Comment: This not change the rules: when you localize your app,  same language IDs are used in the names of the corresponding .lproj language folders.

Comment: Mmmh I think you try to find other storyboards in other languages: you can't, you find the strings translations. Please take a look to this link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW3

Comment: Different things happen to different devices: you could have a storyb file to iphone, a storyb to ipad...

Comment: No No i want to use the same storyboard but changing the current storyboard remotely without update the app from applestore

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not possible. The appstore read a binary stored to itunes repositories, you speak about a code visual tool that should be compiled , archived, approved...

Comment: So Alessandro dont had a way to update the app without pass to the appstore?

Example remote content

In android i got do this

Comment: No Yuri, Apple have strict rules about it. The only way is to recompile the old binary with a new version and re-send to iTunes connect the new package for approval.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations Alessandro